# Is there a way to change a column's type when returning a dataset from a procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I'm basically looking to do something like this:

```
SELECT MYCOLUMN AS 'MYALIAS' VARCHAR(500) 
FROM MYTABLE
```

What I'm doing is this:

```
SELECT COLUMN1 AS 'TEXT',
COLUMN 2 AS 'VALUE'
FROM MYTABLE
```

`COLUMN2` is an `INT` column, however I need to append a string value with UNION as an "Other" selection. Is there a way to return that column as `VARCHAR` instead without actually building the table beforehand and using `INSERT INTO` with a `CONVERT()`? If not, no big deal, I was just looking to see if there was a slick way of doing it.

Comment: You can use a `CONVERT` or `CAST` in the `SELECT` clause: `SELECT CAST(MYCOLUMN AS VARCHAR(500)) FROM ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always cast the column to another type:

```
SELECT 
    COLUMN1,
    CAST(COLUMN2 AS VARCHAR(500))
FROM MYTABLE
```

The approach you have (*`AS 'TEXT'`*) only defines an alias - a different name - for the columns - it does **not** influence the data type in any way.

Comment: Perfect. I understand the alias part, that's just how I had it written out. I'm not THAT big of a newb. =) Thanks, marc.